# determine whether ¬(p∨¬(p→q))∨p is a tautology by using laws of logic.

Tags: propositional-calculus

¬(p ∨ ¬(p→q)) ∨ p ≡ ¬(p ∨ ¬(¬p ∨ q) ∨p (implication rule)
                  ≡ ¬(p ∨(p ∨ ¬q) ∨p (double negation rule)
                  ≡ ¬(p ∨ p) ∨ ¬q) ∨p (associative rule)
                  ≡ ¬((p ∨ ¬q)∨p (Idempotent rule)
                  ≡ (¬p ∨ q) ∨p(double negation rule) *I put the negation into p,do i need to change the sign?
                  ≡ p v (¬p v q)
                  .
                  .
                  .

Hi, I am new to discrete mathematics and i have no idea whether this is correct or not. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: NO; line 2: instead of double negation, you need De Morgan.

Comment: Also watch the brackets.  You should always have the same count for $($ as for $)$.

Comment: I would prefer to see $(\neg (p\lor \neg (p\to q))\lor p$ even though the extra brackets make it harder to read, in order to be  clear about the    "reach" of the first "$\neg$". That is, to distinguish it from $\neg ((p\lor (\neg (p\to q))\lor p).$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}\neg(p \lor \neg(p\to q)) \lor p &\equiv \neg(p ∨ \neg(\neg p \lor q) \color{red})\lor p \text{(implication rule)  }\\
                  &\equiv \neg(p \lor(p \color{red}{\land} ¬q)\color{red}) ∨p \text{(double negation rule and De Morgan) }\\ 
                  &\equiv \neg(p ) \lor p \\
&\equiv T
\end{align}

In your second and fourth step, remember that when you bring in the negation, use De Morgan's rule.

Answer (score 0):

As Mauro noted, you have an issue in your second line--you actually misapply DeMorgan's law (the disjunction should change to a conjunction), but you really do not need to use it there.

You are also consistently missing a right-hand parenthesis throughout.

Consider the following (I'll leave it to you to label the deductions.):
$$
\begin{align*}
\neg[p\lor\neg(p\to q)]\lor p
&\equiv [\neg p\land(\neg p\lor q)]\lor p\\[1em]
&\equiv (\neg p\land\neg p)\lor(\neg p\land q)\lor p\\[1em]
&\equiv (\neg p\lor p)\lor(\neg p\land q)\\[1em]
&\equiv \mathbf{T}\lor(\neg p\land q)\\[1em]
&\equiv\mathbf{T}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice :)